# Can not locate element by its ID in Appium

Tags: android, selenium, appium, selenium-chromedriver

For some reason I am getting the timeout error when looking for an element by its ID.

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds
>   waiting for visibility of element located by By.id:
>   contact-main

The element is definitely present **and is not within a frame**. Using chrome inspector I can easily find the element from console by using

```
$('#contact-main')
```

Yet, the following code produces the above mentioned error:

```
waitFor(30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("contact-main")));
WebElement contactProfileMainContainer = driver.findElement(By.id("contact-main"));
```

Environment: 
Appium 1.5.3.
Hybrid mobile aplication running in Emulator with Android 22

Ideas/suggestions?

Comment: I think you are missing to pass `by.id` as `waitFor(30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("contact-main")));`...may be it this typo mistake or real mistake??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur you are right. That's a typo though. In the actual code I have a class-wide variable declared as such: private By CONTACT_PROFILE_MAIN_CONTAINER = By.id("contact-profile-main"); But while posting the question I decided to simplify it for readability an missed the important part. Will edit now. THanks

Comment: Could you share your HTML as well??

Comment: @YuZhang It is an Angular based app and the html is quite large which is why I refrained from posting it. My hope was that someone has encountered a similar issue and had some ideas to share.

Comment: @Aram did you try using `ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated`..??